# Python TCP Threading

Tags: python, networking, tcp, udp

I have a program that has the following structure

```
2 Threads
1 socket

Thread 1:
Sending data to different clients

Thread 2:
Receiving data from different clients
```

Can I use the same socket for this application?
Or should I use different port number socket for sending and receiving  data?

Answer (score 0):

**SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer** module can be used to handle tcp request and response in multithreading.

```
import SocketServer
import sys

class MyTCPHandle(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mockserver = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', int(sys.argv[1])), MyTCPHandle)

    mockserver.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

The description is quite inadequate - If there are same clients to which you want to send data to and receive data from, a standard practice is one socket per connection (TCP) or if your application is UDP, you can indeed just use just one socket - except that - you've to do a lot of state maintenance in the application. (eg. getting the remote address in recvfrom - storing it in some structure for later use and using that to sendto to other end). Also - when you have two threads - any access to 'shared state should be synchronized' adding additional overhead. So unless you can tell concretely about what is it that you want to do - a good strategy is hard to tell.